# Understanding $\text{Arg}(1+z) - \text{Arg}(1 - z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

I am wondering why $\frac{2}{\pi}[\text{Arg}(1+z) - \text{Arg}(1-z)]$ is equal to $u(z) = (2 \pi)(\varphi + \psi)$ where $\varphi$, $\psi$ are the angles represented in the figure. I normally think of adding complex numbers as vectors, and the picture doesn't make sense to me.

[image]

Comment: For complex $w$ (and a choice of branch cut) $\operatorname{Arg}(w)$ is a real number. Roughly speaking, $\operatorname{Arg}(w)$ is the angle the vector from $0$ to $w$ makes with the positive $x$-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1-z$ is the vector with tail at $z$ and head at $1.$

The argument is the angle that this vector forms with the x axis.

$Arg (1-z)  = -\psi$

$1+z = z-(-1)$ is the vector with head at z and tail at $-1.$

$Arg (1+z)  = \phi$

Comment: I see the second part, but i still don't understand why $\text{Arg}(1-z) = - \psi$. $\text{Arg}$ is supposed to evaluate the angle between the vector and the origin, not the x-axis.

Comment: There is no angle between a vector and the origin.  You need two non-zero vectors to form an angle.

Comment: Okay I see now, you move the tail of $1-z$ to the origin, and this will make two parallel vectors with tails on the x-axis which means we have the same angles in opposite directions. Thank you.